# Take a picture on android camera without click on button or screen

Tags: android, email, android-layout, camera, android-camera-intent

I want to receive a code through SMS from other device in **BroadcastReciever** and on that code receive open camera activity immediately and take a picture of surrounding and then close camera automatically if any one understand me help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NO

That would be a security breach !

Android's camera API doesn't allow photos to be taken automatically without the knowledge of the end user.

However, you could write your own custom camera App and try to build this feature on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
camera.takePicture (null, null, pictureCallback);

private PictureCallback   pictureCallback   = new PictureCallback () {
  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken (final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set particular code for message when that message comes on recieve of that message call method to take photo that you want.

Comment: You just repeated what the OP said in different words.

Comment: yes i want to take a picture when message received. but there is a special command in message to take a picture it works like spy camera